# Parallel Printer GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import binascii
from thread import start_new_thread
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
D0=18
D1=23
D2=24
D3=25
D4=12
D5=16
D6=20
D7=21
STR=13
ACK=5
BUSY=6
GPIO.setup(D0, GPIO.IN) #D0
GPIO.setup(D1, GPIO.IN) #D1
GPIO.setup(D2, GPIO.IN) #D2
GPIO.setup(D3, GPIO.IN) #D3
GPIO.setup(D4, GPIO.IN) #D4
GPIO.setup(D5, GPIO.IN) #D5
GPIO.setup(D6, GPIO.IN) #D6
GPIO.setup(D7, GPIO.IN) #D7
GPIO.setup(STR, GPIO.IN) #STROBE
GPIO.setup(ACK, GPIO.OUT) #ACKN
GPIO.setup(BUSY, GPIO.OUT) #BUSY
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #TEST
global D0_value
global D1_value
global D2_value
global D3_value
global D4_value
global D5_value
global D6_value
global D7_value
global data1
a=1
output=""
b=1
pin_list= [21,20,16,12,25,24,23,18]
GPIO.output(ACK, 1)
def bin2ascii(output):
        global b
        global bin
        global ascii
        bin=filter(str.isdigit, repr(output))
        ascii="".join(("0b", bin))
        n=int(ascii,2)
        print(binascii.unhexlify('%x' % n))
        GPIO.output(BUSY, 0)
        GPIO.output(ACK, 1)
def waitforstrobe(callback):
        global output
        GPIO.output(BUSY, 1)     
        GPIO.output(ACK, 0)
        data1=[GPIO.input(x) for x in pin_list]
        if not output:
                output=data1
        else:
                output+=data1
        GPIO.output(ACK, 1)
        start_new_thread(bin2ascii,(output,))
GPIO.add_event_detect(STR, GPIO.FALLING, callback=waitforstrobe, bouncetime=10)
print("Waiting for printsignal...")
GPIO.output(BUSY, 0)
```

Hey everyone, 
I'm New in programming with rasbian.

I want to Program my pi  3 so that the pi will display the printer data.

I soldered all data lines, strobe acknowledge and busy  lines to the GPIOs with a Level converter.

My Problem is that the program Shows only wrong ascii Charakters Decoded from the data lines.

I have the feeling that the reading and decoding procedure is to slow, so that not all binary data are captured.

Do you have any idea, so that the prog works better?

STR input is Set from PC to signal that data can be read.
Busy is the from pi always when busy.
ACK(acknowledge) is set to low when not ready to read next 8 bit and Set to high when ready for next data set.

Many thanks for help!

Comment: Python is probably way too slow for this. Also your code to convert binary to ASCII is much, much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your answer. Is it in C More stable? And How I can improve the ascii conVersion code?

Comment: Being slow or inefficiently-coded doesn't mean you will get corrupt out, just slow output. As long as the data is stable when the strobe is puled you should get correct output if you wired everything correctly. You must have a problem somewhere in your code or wiring. You could try making the output a known character with all zeroes and exactly one 1 (e.g. @ is decimal 64), and check the printed character to work out the code the printer is receiving. Then add a single 1 to the output and see what character is being printed to work out what code is being received. Repeat...